# In sequelize how to "order" on "limit" data?

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to know how to `order` on `limit` data on `sequelize`. Means, after getting `limit: 10`, `offset: 0` data from `findAll` or `findAndCountAll` in `ASC` or `DESC` order, I want to know if I can `order` the `limit: 10` data as well ?

Comment: What do you mean by ordering the adta you got using `limit: 10`? If you indicate all needed columns in `order` option won't you get what you want ?

Comment: I meant, first I want whole data in `DESC` order with `limit: 10`, and the `10` data I will get I want that in `ASC` order each time.

Comment: I suppose it's better to sort then afterwards in memory

Comment: I did it, but I thought `sequelize` has method for this already, as raw query can solve this issue easily.

Comment: Nope, it hasn't